# Lubuntu updated to 20.04 - Volume and brightness controls stopped working

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, shortcut-keys

My laptop is Lenovo B50. After I upgraded from Lubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 (switching to LXQT), the volume and brightness adjustment buttons on keyboard no longer work. Stangely, other Fn buttons work, like turning off the screen.

I tried different changes in ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml, even changing the default brightnes command to "lxqt-config-brightness -d" (as it works from terminal), but nothing works.

If it helps - each session starts with a "shortcuts can not be registered:XF86AudioMute" notification, and on the boot screen I get an error "1.55 no irq handler for vector", which didn't happen before the upgrade.

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 required a re-install due to desktop change. Refer https://lubuntu.me/focal-released/ which states *due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install*.  Yes it's possible (my own system was such an upgrade), but problems were to be expected

Comment: Maybe helpful: the Lubuntu team wrote some documentation on upgrading 18.04 (LXDE) systems to 18.10 (LXQt) which you maybe able to find and may contain clues (it wasn't published so you won't find it on their web site, a search engine will find it you don't already know where I'm talking about). It was never updated as the upgrade option was abandoned, but it's the place I'd head for clues on fixing problems (where I went though it was 18.04->18.10 when I bumped).

Comment: Thank you, seems like happily pressing "Upgrade" without a second thought wasn't the best idea. I think a fresh install would be the best solution.

Comment: If you download the Lubuntu 20.04(.1) LTS ISO & boot it in *live* mode, you can confirm the issue is not kernel related (your 18.04 system would have been using 4.15 if you were using the GA stack, though 5.4 if using the HWE stack).  I'd just confirm it works there before re-install, but you'll need to re-install anyway sometime as Lubuntu 18.04 LTS being a *flavor* only has 3 years of fully-supported life (`ubuntu-support-status` will confirm the packages reaching EOL 2021-April)...

Answer (score 0):

Installing Lubuntu 20.04 from scratch fixed the main problem, except the irq error but that seems to be not related.